# complex numbers inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that |z|=1. Prove that $|1+z|+|1+z^2|+|1+z^3|\geq2$

I have tried using the triangle inequality by grouping the first and last module after expending $|1+z^3|$ and then grouping it all with $|1+z^2|$. I arrived at $$|z^3+z^2+z+1+2|=\left|\frac{1-z^4}{1-z}+2\right|$$

How do I prove that this is greater or equal than 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: We have
$$2=(1+z^3)+(1+z^2)-z^2(1+z)$$

Comment: No; simply use  the fact that if $a,b,c$ are complex numbers we have $|a+b+c|\leq |a|+|b|+|c|$

Comment: Put $a=1+z^3$, $b=1+z^2$, $c=-z^2(1+z)$, and apply the inequality above.